# how to change this macro and make it resuable?

Tags: c++, macros

I have two Macro.

```
#define CONCAT(arg1, arg2)  arg1##arg2
#define API_M(keyword)\
public: \
static Return_Type CONCAT(keyword, wrapper)(passingtype1 *ptr1, \
passingtype2 *ptr2, passingtype3 *ptr3)\
{  return ptr1-> keyword(ptr2, ptr3); }
```

note: this keyword and wrapper is just string.  and the Macro API_M(keyword)

has been widely used in the whole code.

My object is to remove this MACRO and make the replacement code reusable, otherwise it will have a lot of duplicate code.

Could any one give me any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert the macro to a function?

Comment: Actually i am not sure what i can do. because the API_M(keyword) is also define within another class.   class another_class{  API_M(keyword);  other data member or function  }

Comment: But I think it should be a function.

Comment: "widely used in the whole world"  Oh, really?

Comment: Looks like a job for templates.

Comment: i don't thinks so ,the template need type, but for me, i just need string.